# Multiple What IF Statement in Excel for Soccer score project

Tags: excel

I have a long list of soccer data but in it's most simplistic form it looks like this:

```
A1 Barcelona
A2 Madrid
A3 2
A4 1
A5 (this will be the IF Statement)
```

There are over 200 rows but all with the same premice, so what I want is an if statement that says if the score in A3 is larger than A4 then A5 has a W and if A4 is a larger score than A3 than A5 has an L

Can someone give me some pointers as to how to do this, only need to know it for the top line of the data and then I can replicate throughout

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if statement:

```
=IF(A3>A4,"W",IF(A4>A3,"L",IF(A3=A4,"Tie","")))
```